# App.config decryption fails after a reboot

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption

We have a WPF application where we encrypt our connection strings after a first read:

```
Configuration config = OpenConfiguration(configFileName);

ConfigurationSection configSection = config.GetSection(sectionName);

if (configSection == null)
    return false;

if (!configSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
{
    if (!configSection.SectionInformation.IsLocked)
    {
        configSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
        config.Save();
    }
}
```

We have this on hundreds of machines, so far everything has worked great. After the first run, the plain text connection strings are encrypted. The decryption should just work automatically. However, we have one machine which is unable to decrypt this information after Windows has rebooted.

My understanding is that the "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider" uses something system specific as its encryption key. 
Has anyone got any ideas that may help me track down the problem? I am a bit stumped as to why it is this one machine that isn't working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have very limited security doing this if you are trying to hide the connection string from the user because if your application can decrypt then so can anyone with a compiler and Google.

Comment: the software runs on locked down systems using windows embedded. So for us this is good enough as the only people that should ever see it are  our on-site teams.

Comment: ok, when I see WPF it usually means user-facing.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close off this issue, the problem is now solved.

There was an issue with the deployment to this particular machine, the MD5 checksum of the files was on the machine in question were different. A Manual install of the files has cleared this issue up.